# How do I pass info learned by WiX Custom Action to install subsequent components

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle, oracle11g, wix, odbc

Our business requirement is to install and configure Oracle Client software on many client machines which are prerequisites for all of our custom corporate Excel and MS Access documents which use ODBC to access the native Oracle drivers.

So here's what I want WiX to do for me in Visual Studio 2010:

1. Use a bootstrapper to chain several packages together.
2. The last package in the chain will run a custom MSI called ConfigOracleClient.msi.
3. ConfigOracleClient.msi runs a custom action which examines the Oracle Client(s) on the machine, and determines the path(s) in which the Oracle Homes are located.
4. Use the paths learned to install some custom DSN's which point to the proper drivers.
5. Install a file named TNSNAMES.ORA into the proper path.

In VS2010, I have made three projects in my solution:

1. The Bootstrapper (InstallPrerequisites.exe)
2. The ConfigOracleClient.msi, which contains the OdbcDsns.wxi and the TNSNames.ORA text file
3. The OracleCustomAction.CA.dll

The action of passing the path learned by the custom action back to the ConfigOracleClient.msi, in order to ask it to install the DSNs and the TNSNames.ORA is too hard for me to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to make sure that the folder which contains your files (TNSNAMES.ORA & DSN's) inside the ConfigOracleClient.msi **uses a public installer property (no lowercase letters in its name) as its ID.**

Then you can use one of these custom action to change the property value during install:

1. a custom action which changes the directory property value scheduled before CostFinalize
2. a type 35 custom action which changes the directory path (should be scheduled after CostFinalize)

For example:

```
<CustomAction Id="ChangeDir" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="SomeValueorPropertyhere]"/>
```

"SomeValueorPropertyhere" is what you determine within your custom action.

2.Schedule the action during the InstallExecution phase (must be after the CostFinalize step):

```
<Custom Action="ChangeDir" After="CostFinalize"></Custom>
```

Also please make sure that the custom action which you currently use to determine the Oracel Home path, executes before the custom action "ChangeDir".

Comment: This is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705559/wix-changing-the-path-of-a-directory-does-not-change-the-path-of-a-sub-director